# User account activation email - protocol repeated twice (django)

Tags: python, django

In this scenario, I am looking for the user to receive an email to activate their account.

This email will contain a link for them to click on for the activation link.

For some reason, the protocol `"https://"` is repeated twice in the email.

In this case the code renders: "`https://https://sitename.com/...`"

However, I do not encounter this problem when I run the code on my local host.

I am using Django and deploying on Heroku (just in case it matters).

Here is the code.

I tried rewriting the views where the protocol is handled:

```py
"protocol": 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http' 
#to 
"protocol": '' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
```

but no success, the protocol is still repeated twice.

**Template file**

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi,

Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

**views.py**

```py
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except:
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can log in your account.")
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.error(request,"Activation link is invalid")   
    return redirect('home')

def activateEmail(request, user, to_email):
    mail_subject = "Activate your user account"
    message = render_to_string("main/template_activate_account.html", {
        'user': user.username,
        'domain': get_current_site(request).domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        "protocol": 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
    })
    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
    if email.send():
        messages.success(request,f'Dear <b>(new_user)</b>, please go to your email<b>(to_email)</b> inbox and click on \ recieved activation link to confirm and complete the registration. <b>Note:</b>Check your spam folder.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, f'Problem sending email to {to_email}, check if you typed it correctly.')

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active=False
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                password = form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
            login(request,user)
            activateEmail(request, user, form.cleaned_data.get('email'))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            for error in list(form.errors.values()):
                messages.error(request, error)
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'main/registration/register_user.html',{'form':form})
```

**settings.py**

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM = 'XX'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XX'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XX'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True

PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 14400
```

**tokens.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
import six

class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return(
            six.text_type(user.pk)+ six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )
        
account_activation_token=AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Comment: What does `is_secure()` actually return for you on production? Also, what's the value of `get_current_site(request).domain`? I think probably the simplest solution for you would be to double check your `sites` and remove the protocol from the domain there. See the [docs on the sites framwork](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site).

Comment: Looks like you gave me some homework to do! Going to have a look at this tonight!